# Laravel: How to validate that a variable is an array OR a string matching a regex

Tags: php, validation, laravel

I want to validate that a variable is either an array OR a string matching a regex. Can this be accomplished with a single rule using Laravel validation?

Here's an example of what I want :

```
// Does not work because the validation tries to match ALL conditions
$rules = [
    'keys' => 'array|regex:\d+'
];

$validation = Validator::make(['keys' => '12345'], $rules);

if ($validation->fails()) {
    // This is getting executed because it is not an array
} else {
    // Do something else
}
```

I already have a workaround by using 2 different validator objects (each with one of the conditions) and checking if one of them passes, but I would like to know if there is a more "elegant" solution built in Laravel.

Answer (score 6):

The most "elegant" workaround I can think of is creating a [Custom Validation Rule](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#custom-validation-rules), but you could also try [conditionally adding the array and the regex rules](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/validation#conditionally-adding-rules).

But how about the obvious, checking the type of the variable in order to add the appropriate rule?

```
//dummy data, could be from $request->all()
$data = ['keys' => '12345'];

$rules = [
    'keys' => is_array($data['keys']) ? 'array' : 'regex:\d+'
];

$validation = Validator::make($data, $rules);
```

Quick and simple, but it's a waste of an array check and will always give the regex error message.

Answer (score 0):

In case some still needs it: my solution (in Laravel9) is to use the prepareForValidation function to convert the occasional string to an array before validation happens.

```
protected function prepareForValidation()
{
    if(! is_array($this->images)) {
        $this->images = [$this->images];
    }
}
```